# Why can I reference tables in the select new which aren't in the select from statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a SQL Server database which i'm querying with Entity Framework.

I want to get row counts of various tables but also minimise the round trip to the database. So I using the "select new" to return an anonymised type containing the various counts.

I don't understand why i'm allowed to query multiple tables in the statement when the "in db.Submissions" would indicate results are restricted to a single table.

What, if any, are the implications of doing this?

```
            var counts = (from s in db.Submissions
                    select new
                    {
                        s1 = db.Submissions.Count(i => i.SubmittedDateTime >= yesterday),
                        s2 = db.Submissions.Count(i => i.SubmittedDateTime >= lastweek),
                        s3 = db.Submissions.Count(i => i.SubmittedDateTime >= lastfortnight),
                        s4 = db.Submissions.Count(),
                        cr1 = db.ContactRequests.Count(i => i.ContactRequestDateTime >= yesterday),
                        cr2 = db.ContactRequests.Count(i => i.ContactRequestDateTime >= lastweek),
                        cr3 = db.ContactRequests.Count(i => i.ContactRequestDateTime >= lastfortnight),
                        cr4 = db.ContactRequests.Count(),
                        l1 = db.Log.Count(i => i.LogDateTime >= yesterday),
                        l2 = db.Log.Count(i => i.LogDateTime >= lastweek),
                        l3 = db.Log.Count(i => i.LogDateTime >= lastfortnight),
                        l4 = db.Log.Count(),
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Executes successfully with correct values, eg:
{ s1 = 0, s2 = 6, s3 = 6, s4 = 6, cr1 = 0, cr2 = 1, cr3 = 1, cr4 = 1, l1 = 0, l2 = 0 ... }

Comment: Could the table `Submissions` have foreign keys to other tables?

Comment: Yes, the table does have some FKs and ContactRequests is one of them. However, in the production code I'm actually querying a lot more counts than i have illustrated above, and some of the tables used definitely don't have a PK/FK relationship back to the Submissions table!!

Comment: Ok, but is it possible that the table `ContactRequests` also has FKs to these other tables and so on.

Comment: Unfortunately, not entirely. There is a table called Log, where ASP.Net logs any exceptions found. That is entirely independent of all other tables with no PK/FK relationships (I've just double checked). This also works fine above -- will update the question to show this.

Comment: Why shouldn't you be allowed? The underlying database engine supports this just fine, `SELECT u.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Logs WHERE Logs.UserId = u.Id) AS LogCount FROM Users u`.

Comment: Actually I think this more closely resembles the query @LasseVågsætherKarlsen `SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Logs) AS LogCount FROM Submissions s`

Comment: The implication could be that the query is actually sent as multiple queries to the database engine with multiple round trips instead of one.